# Pinch zoom with dynamic pins on custom image

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I want exactly this:
http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/sample5.html
I want a pinch to zoom ImageView with dynamic pins on it.
It is for a game where you have an ingame Map.
So I want to make this ingame Map zoomable and put some landmarks on it.
Is there any tutorial out there?
Please send me a link, thank you very much.

Comment: https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage this library should help

Comment: @AkashKhatri To programm a pinch zoom is not my problem. I want to put some landmarks on the ImageView who stay fixed just like in the example I postet in my question.

Comment: I think you can use canvas or drawable matrix for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touch imageview class

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

Simply add TouchImageview in layout file

```
<com.partymosaics.utils.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/background_drawable"

    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```